# How to remove white pixels on the corners after border-radius

Tags: html, css

I've created a simple unordered list with rounded corners, when selecting a list item I want the background to become blue to show the active state. When I have no border-radius everything looks great.

However, when I use a border-radius of 4px to round all the edges, and select the last list item (#5) with the rounded corners on the bottom, the blue active state now shows small white pixels on the corners. I can't seem to figure out how to prevent this from happening. Thanks for any help. .

http://jsfiddle.net/8PN8Z/

Code snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  $('a.tab-link').click(function() {
    $('a.tab-link').removeClass('active-tab')
    $(this).addClass('active-tab')
  });
});
```

```css
.left-dash {
  background: #444;
  height: 500px;
}

.left-dash div {
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}

.left-dash div ul li:first-child,
.left-dash div ul li:first-child a {
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
}

.left-dash div ul li:last-child,
.left-dash div ul li:last-child a {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
}

.dash-stats-3 {
  width: 220px;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
  background: #9f9f9f;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  /* for transparent border with solid bg - Safari */
  background-clip: padding-box;
  /* for IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome */
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 0px #FFFFFF, 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 0px #FFFFFF, 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 0px #FFFFFF, 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 0px #FFFFFF, 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  font-family: 'Museo Sans W01 700' san-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #828282;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: normal !important;
}

.dash-stats-3 ul li a,
.dash-stats-3 ul li:first-child {
  height: 41px;
  border-bottom: solid rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.15) 1px;
  border-top: solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .65) 1px;
}

.left-dash div ul li:last-child,
.left-dash div ul li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.dash-stats-3 ul li a {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 43px;
  display: block;
}

.dash-stats-3 ul li a.active-tab {
  z-index: 120;
  border-top: 1px solid #5b82a7;
  background: #4e81be;
  /* Old browsers */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-dash">
  <div class="dash-stats-3">
    <ul class="dash-stats-3-ul">
      <li><span id="explore-themes">testing</span></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="tab-link" data-remote="true">
          <span class="ss-pika ss-icon">1</span><span class="theme"> test-1</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href=# "" class="tab-link" data-remote="true">
          <span class="ss-pika ss-icon">2</span><span class="theme"> test-2</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="tab-link" data-remote="true">
          <span class="ss-pika ss-icon">3</span><span class="theme"> test-3</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/theme/inspiring" class="tab-link" data-remote="true">
          <span class="ss-pika ss-icon">4</span><span class="theme"> test-4</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="tab-link" data-remote="true">
          <span class="ss-pika ss-icon">5</span><span class="theme"> test-5</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you're applying something on a div (box-shadow maybe?) that you should apply to each indiividual li or even link. Parent div doesn't know that border-radius is being applied on some of its children and it should to adapt for it.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. I don't think it's possible to have the box-shadow applied to the individual li's or links, that would make each box have it's own drop shadow instead of the entire unordered list. I'm confused why the parent div would cause issues if the border-radius for everything is identical?

Comment: This code is gnarly. I suggest taking it down a notch and distilling the problem down to something simple. I have never seem !important used in a jsfiddle before. These selectors are insanity. I think you might be over-thinking this. Also - you might want to note that sometimes border radius just looks weird when it's like, 4px etc - the average screen can't render it smoothly because it's so small and the pixels blah blah blah. check it on a retina screen as a side test.

Answer (score 0):

First, give the `active-tab` a radius.

```
.dash-stats-3 ul li a.active-tab {
    z-index:120;
    border-top: 1px solid #5b82a7;
    background: #4e81be; /* Old browsers */ 
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 2px 2px;
        border-radius: 0px 0px 2px 2px;  
}
```

Make sure its smaller than the `li`'s radius, (2px).

And remove the radius for the `a` in its default state. Remove this.

```
.left-dash div ul li:last-child a{
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px; 
}
```

Keep this.

```
.left-dash div ul li:last-child{
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px; 
}
```

Check it out : http://jsfiddle.net/FcXVY/

The problem is that you're giving a child element the same border radius as the parent element. Even if the parent element won't have a border, there will be some tiny pixels shown, and with a border, its worse. Check this out : http://jsfiddle.net/UVTJQ/

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I see that the way you accomplished this is to change the border-radius on the active-tab to 2px instead of 4px. Is there no way to keep the border-radius consistent throughout?

Comment: @trying_hal9000 I updated my answer, check the example, and remove the border from the parent, there will still be some pixels shown, the only way to solve this is to have an absolute child, that will completely cover the parent when it has `top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;` (Need to be tested)

Comment: @trying_hal9000 If you can sacrifice the `<a>` inside the `<li>`, and work on the `li` instead, clicking on it, coloring it, coloring its border blue as well, I think you'll avoid this problem.

Comment: Hi thanks again for the help. I tired using only li's and the problem still exists. I never knew about the issues with parents and child border-radius. I worked together a hack using your method above where javascript also changes the parent div's border-radius to 6px so that the 4px border radius of the active-tab is still smaller than the parent http://jsfiddle.net/E2jk3/. It seems to work but also seems to be much more js code

Comment: @trying_hal9000 Nice trick, and don't worry about using JS, I know doing things with pure css is better, but JS is everywhere, and using it isn't a shame. The issue with parent and child border radius doesn't even get solved with absolute child ( I tested it ), of course if the size is small, it won't be noticed, because extra pixels are barely 2 pixels, I think this is rendering issue, could be different between a browser and another.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I think this simplifies things. Check It out. I hope it helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/8WTam/

```
<ul class="test-list">
    <li><a href="?">Item thing</a></li>
    <li><a href="?">Item thing</a></li>
    <li><a href="?">Item thing</a></li>
    <li><a href="?">Item thing</a></li>
    <li><a href="?">Item thing</a></li>
    <li><a href="?">Item thing</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
/* border box - google it. it rules*/ 
* { 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.test-list {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;

    /* just to show the properly containing ul */  
    margin: 2em;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    padding: 1em;
}

.test-list li {

}

.test-list a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    background-color: #f06;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    min-width: 12em;

    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
    border-bottom: 0;
}

.test-list a:hover {
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: black;
}

.test-list li:first-of-type a {
    -webkit-border-radius:.4em .4em 0 0;
    border-radius: .4em .4em 0 0;
}

.test-list li:last-of-type a {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 .4em .4em;
    border-radius: 0 0 .4em .4em;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}
```

Comment: or maybe you want `box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 .2em rgba(255,255,255,.5);` in there... on the a --- I'm starting to question if I understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help but this solution doesn't really solve my problem, if I were able to do an entire redesign I guess I could use this solution. Just FYI since you were concerned, the !important is there because I copied and pasted code from a project into the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs because the border-radius of the list items and the links aren't the same. The discrepancy in the radius between the li and the a elements causes the white pixels to appear.

To fix it, apply the border-radius to only the a elements, not the li elements. Also, ensure you're setting an overflow: hidden on the parent container to handle any child elements that might overflow the parent's border-radius.

Your CSS should look something like this:

```
.left-dash div ul li:first-child a {
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

.left-dash div ul li:last-child a {
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}
```

And remove the border-radius from **.left-dash div ul li:first-child** and **.left-dash div ul li:last-child** selectors.

This should fix the issue of the white corners appearing.